# Python VNC ip scanner error

Tags: python, vnc

Hello i'm so confused on why i am getting this error

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -w
import random
import socket
from random import randint

username = 'admin'
password = 'admin'

print 'Format:'
print '101.109'
range = raw_input("Range: ")

def main():
    return '%s.%i.%i' % (range, rand(), rand())

def rand():
    return randint (1,254)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

while True:
    print 'Scanning %s:%s - %s' % (username, password, main())
    port = (5900)
    s.connect((main(), port))
```

Error code:

```
Format:
101.109
Range: 101.109
Scanning admin:admin - 101.109.154.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aries\Desktop\crap\Reflect.py", line 24, in <module>
    s.connect((main(), port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

So my friend wanted me to make a VNC IP scanner so thats what im doing and im making it try to connect to it finds actual VNC ips but when its doing that i get an error as you see at the top

EDIT: MORE INFO

I need to know how i can make it not give me an error if the connection is not up

Comment: Catch the exception handle it however you want: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions, or https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `connect` in a `try/except` block:

```
Host = main()
try:
    s.connect((Host, port))
    print "Port {} is open on host {}".format(port, Host)
except:
    print "Connection failed" # or just pass
```